# fetch an image from mongodb to reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, localhost

I'm new to mongodb and nodejs, I saved a post that has texts and image to mongodb database,
and I'm trying to get the info, the image appears to be undefined.

this is the post model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema, model } = mongoose;
const postSchema = new Schema(
  {
    title: String,
    summary: String,
    content: String,
    file: String,
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const PostModel = model("Post", postSchema);

module.exports = PostModel;
```

in the server side, i'm passing the image using multer middleware

```
const multer = require("multer");
const blogStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, callback) => {
    callback(null, "./api/postblog");
  },
  filename: (req, file, callback) => {
    callback(null, `${Date.now()}_${file.originalname}`);
  },
});

const postblog = multer({ storage: blogStorage });

app.post("/post", postblog.single("file"), async (req, res) => {
  const { title, summary, content } = req.body;
  const { originalname, path } = req.file;
  const newPath = path;
  const postDoc = await Post.create({
    title,
    summary,
    content,
    file: newPath,
  });
  res.json(postDoc);
});

app.get("/post/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const postDoc = await Post.findById(id);
  res.json(postDoc);
});
```

and this is the page postPage.js where I get the post by id

```
const PostPage = () => {

   const [postInfo, setPostInfo] = useState(null);
   const { userInfo } = useContext(UserContext);
   const { id } = useParams();
   useEffect(() => {
     fetch(`http://localhost:4000/post/${id}`).then((response) => {
       response.json().then((postInfo) => {
         setPostInfo(postInfo);
       });
     });
   }, []);

   if (!postInfo) return "";

  return (
    <div className="post-page">
      <h1>{postInfo.title}</h1>
      <time>{formatISO9075(new Date(postInfo.createdAt))}</time>
      <div className="image">
        <img src={`http://localhost:4000/${postInfo.cover}`} alt="" />
      </div>
      <div
        className="content"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: postInfo.content }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default PostPage
```

I get all the files but the image, the console shows : undefined_1678239862173_bg.jpg.jpg:1          GET http://localhost:4000/api/postblog/undefined_1678239862173_bg.jpg.jpg 404 (Not Found)

this is my mongodb document :

[Post collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sXf6.png)

and this is my project structure :
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ku0yr.png)

I tried this line of code : app.use("/postblog", express.static(__dirname + "/postblog"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this with https://cloudinary.com image backend service,

once the account on cloudinary is created, you will be provided with an APIkey and API secret,
First I downloaded Cloudinary with

> npm install cloudinary

and then included it in server.js

```
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2;
```

- I set up multer to handle the image uploads
- and configured cloudinary to store the images like this

cloudinary.config({
cloud_name: "XXX",
api_key: "XXXXXXXXXX",
api_secret: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
});

and then I stored the data in mongodb like this :

```
  app.post("/post", postblog.single("file"), async (req, res) => {
    const { title, summary, content } = req.body;
    const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path);
    const postDoc = await Post.create({
      title,
      summary,
      content,
      file: result.secure_url,
    });
    res.json(postDoc);
  });
```

and to fetch the image in the client side, you just need to :

```
  const [postInfo, setPostInfo] = useState(null);
  const { id } = useParams();
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:4000/post/${id}`).then((response) => {
      response.json().then((postInfo) => {
        setPostInfo(postInfo);
      });
    });
  }, []);

  if (!postInfo) return "";

  return (
    <div className="image">
      <img src={postInfo.} alt="" />
    </div>
  );
```